# Quick Look won't play sound of .avi files

Tags: audio, quicklook, mediaplayer, video

When I want to use Quick Look to quickly check if an .avi file is corrupt, or if the quality is alright, it does not play the sound anymore.

Is there a way to enhance Quick Look with "proper" divx capabilities, to prevent mishaps like this?

On a related note: I would enjoy .mkv-support, too, if anyone has an idea how to integrate that.

EDIT:
jmlumpkin got it right, Perian solved the problem. I can now quickcheck .avi files again, properly.

Thank you for the quick answer, I would upvote, but it says I need 15 rep first :/

Comment: I think you were talking about Quick Look and not Preview. So I changed your question/answer/tags accordingly.

Comment: Yes, indeed. As I was saying, I'm used to calling both "Vorschau" in German, hence the little confusion. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick Look won't let you do this. Mainly because the core audio/video stuff behind quicktime doesn't support it.

The easiest way to do this would honestly be to use VLC. This supports both file types you mention.

The other way is to check out [Perian](http://perian.org/), which gives you a bunch of extra codecs.

Personally, I would try the VLC way first. You won't be able to view these items with quickview or preview.app, but VLC handles pretty much any file type I have ever thrown at it.

Comment: Well thanks, I already use VLC, especially because of that broadband-file-type-support you mention :) But the thing is that Preview (Or Quick Look, I'm a little confused now. Well, the thing that pop up when pressing the spacebar) used to play .avi files properly, but now it's missing. But thanks, I will look into Perian.

Comment: Yes, quick look is what pops up when you hit space bar. Preview is what 'usually' (as in a default OS install) opens when you open a PDF (by double clicking). I do not exactly remember using Perian with QuickLook, but it all uses the same backend.

Comment: @jemus42 Perial will do, since the backend is the same. Perian allows you to see DivX files (for example) using QuickLook (and time)

Comment: As I edited in my original question, Perian resolved the problem and works just nicely (I know have the ability to preview .mkv files in QuickLook, nice!). As far as the destinction between QuickLook & Preview is concerned, I have to admit that I'm German, and I'm used to call both things "Vorschau" (equivalent zo "Preview"), so, sorry for the confusion.